# TSQL : Is replace better than ltrim/rtrim

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Is replace is better than ltrim/rtrim.**
I have no spaces between the words, because I am running it on key column.

```
  update [db14].[dbo].[S_item_60M]
  set [item_id]=ltrim(rtrim([item_id]))

Item_id having non-clustered index
```

**Shall I disable index for better performance?**

`Windows 7,   24GB RAM    , SQL Server 2014`

This query was running for 20 hours and then I canceled it. I am thinking to run Replace instead of ltrim/rtrim for performance reasons.

SSMS studio crashed.

Now I can see it running in Activity Monitor

```
Error Log says  FlushCache: cleaned up 66725 bufs with 25872 writes in 249039 ms (avoided 11933 new dirty bufs) for db 7:0
```

Please guide and suggest me.

Comment: How many rows are you trying to update? You should probably batch your updates in to "chunks" e.g. 10,000 rows in a single go.

Comment: Why not simply try it out, if there is a difference, it should show even if you run the query on a smaller sample (100, 1,000, 10,000?...) and `compare the actual execution plans taken`

Comment: Besides that, you can probably speed up the update if you pull all contents from the production db-table first into a table variable for example, calculate the changes there (i.e. have 2 columns one for the original `item_id` one for the trimmed on that table variable) then run the update on the actual production table by joining your table variable (that might not actually speed up the whole query but it should reduce locking on the production table)

Answer (score 1):

The throughput of bulk updates does not depend on a single call per row to `ltrim` or `rtrim`. You arbitrarily pick some highly visible element of your query and consider it responsible for bad performance. Look at the query plan to see what's being done physically. Also, make yourself familiar with bulk update techniques (such as dropping and recreating indexes).

Note, that contrary to popular belief a bulk update with all rows in one statement is usually the fastest option. This strategy can cause blocking and high log usage. But is usually has the best throughput because the optimizer can optimize all the DML that you are executing in one plan. If splitting DML into chunks was almost always a good idea SQL Server would just do it automatically as part of the plan.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Please guide me more about this. My table is idle. This is Test database and only this single update statement need to be run on this machine. There must be no locking at all.

Comment: Any concrete questions?

Comment: @user3380585 `no locking at all` this should actually be impossible ;)

Comment: This is newly installed sql server 2014 and no sql operation on it. I need to remove junk charcters from this 60 Million table size 95GB.

Comment: Shall I disable the index on item_id?

Comment: That depends on the schema. Can't tell with given information. You'll be better served by reading a few articles about bulk updates. All of this is well documented.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `REPLACE` versus `LTRIM`/`TRIM` is the long pole in the tent performance wise.  Do you have concurrent activity against the table during the update?  I suggest you perform this operation during a maintenance window to avoid blocking with other queries.

If a lot of rows will be updated (more than 10% or so) I suggest you drop (or disable) the non-clustered index on item_id column, perform the update, and then create (or enable) the index afterward.  Specify the `TABLOCKX` locking hint.

Comment: Thanks for reply. This is test database and idle. This is newly installed sql server 2014 and no sql operation on it. I need to remove junk charcters from this 60 Million table size 95GB.

Comment: I would expect the operation to be much faster without the index.  You can check the query plan to verify, but I suspect it includes additional operators to facilitate a mass update of the indexed column.

Answer (score 1):

If there are some rows which already have no spaces, exclude them from the UPDATE by using a WHERE clause such as CHARINDEX(' ',item_id)<>0. But the most important advice (already posted above by gvee) is to do the UPDATE in batches (if you have a key which you can use for paging). Another aproach (possibly better if you have enough space) would be to use an operation that can be minimally logged (in the bulk-logged or simple recovery model): use a SELECT INTO another table and then rename that table.

Comment: Hey thanks. How to do this in batches? My table wont have any key in it. And adding identity coulmn to it wil be very slow. Is there any trick to do update in batched using TOP (while 1=1 update top 1000 ...)?